# installation of snap-store in kali linux 2020.4

Tags: kali-linux, snap

I was trying to install `snap-store` in `kali linux 2020.4`.

```
sudo install snapd
sudo snap install snap-store
```

I tried above source code. And, I am getting that I have successfully installed **`snap-store`**. [image]

But, when I am trying to run `snap-store`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see I have successfully installed snap-store. But, there's no `snap-store` in my directory. Again, when I tried to run `snap-store` this way.

```
snap run snap-store
```

[image]

Then, I am able to run that way. But, I need `Desktop-Entry` of it..

Look I have installed lot more software also.

[image]

I can only run them via `snap run [package name]`. There's no desktop entry of them. So, it means I have successfully installed `snap-store` only there's no desktop entry of `snap-store` and others.

How to solve it?

Comment: Just a gentle reminder that Kali is designed as a penetration testing environment and doesn't work well as a general use environment. Issues with things not working are very common and users just left to fend for themselves.

Comment: @PhilipCouling earlier I was using `dock`. That moment everything was working correctly. But, after uninstalling the Linux I am not changing dash-to-dock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In earlier versions of Kali (older than 2020.1) you didn't have access to create desktop entry while directly installing any software from snapd. However, if you install gnome in Kali in any version than you will have desktop entry of those files.

I don't know why, whenever I use gnome, I get a desktop entry of those software which I installed from snapd. But, when I don't use gnome, I don't get any desktop entry of those software. I really don't know why this happens. Since then, I always install gnome.

I didn't even have any idea of command lines when I asked the question. As [@Itai Nelken said in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/633060/449077), use

```
ln -st ~/.local/share/applications /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/*.desktop
```

I think this command is "saying" that to take them to another directory.

Also, he warned that,

> I haven't tested it, so I don't know if it will break something. use at your own risk!

So, now I think this could break something. Because, they are not likely to run by `snap run <package name>`, because they aren't in their directory where snap searches for them. That's why it's likely to break.

Answer (score 3):

### From the 2 following links: [installing snap on kali linux](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-kali) [installing the snap-store](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-store-app)

> **Installing snap from a live Kali Linux environment is not currently supported. These instructions only work when Kali Linux is installed.**

From a Kali Linux installation, snap can be installed directly from the command line:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

Additionally, enable and start both the snapd and the snapd.apparmor services with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd apparmor
```

**Finally, either *log out and back in again*, or *restart your system*, to ensure snap’s paths are updated correctly. if you don't do this step, menu shortcuts won't appear!**

The Snap Store app is installed with the following command:

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

now reboot or at least log out and back in. if the menu shortcuts still don't appear you can try to run this command: `ln -st ~/.local/share/applications /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/*.desktop`
**I haven't tested it, so I don't know if it will break something. use at your own risk!**

Comment: *This should be the accepted answer* - the other (accepted) answer, which was posted by the OP, is merely a comment about this answer.